# JSXGraph - how to update an interpolating polynomial in terms of the number of points?

Tags: interpolation, jsxgraph

I am trying to write a simple script to demonstrate Runge's phenomenon: that polynomials interpolated on equidistant points fit a non-polynomial function very badly as the number of points increases - basically such polynomials show huge oscillations near the end points.

To this end I have Runge's function `1/(1+25*x*x)` plotted between -1.5 and 1.5, and a slider which takes values 3 to 10 in steps of 1.  But I can't get the script to work.  Here's my first try:

```
var i,xval,yval;
var brd = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('runge',{boundingbox: [-1.5, 1.5, 1.5, -1.5],axis:true});

var n = brd.create('slider',[[0.1,1.4],[1.1,1.4],[3,5,10]],{name:'n',snapWidth:1});

var f = brd.create('functiongraph',[function(x){return 1/(1+25*x*x);} ,-1.5,1.5]);

var xy = [];
for (i = 0; i< n.Value(); i++) {
    var xval = -1+2/(n.Value()-1)*i;
    var yval = 1/(1+25*xval*xval);
    xy[i] = brd.create('point',[xval,yval],{name:'', size:2});
}

var poly = JXG.Math.Numerics.lagrangePolynomial(xy);
var g = brd.create('functiongraph',[poly,-1.5,1.5],{strokewidth:2});
}
```

This doesn't work: it shows the interpolation function through three points, and moving the slider does nothing.  I then tried this:

```
var i,xval,yval;
var brd = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('runge',{boundingbox: [-1.5, 1.5, 1.5, -1.5],axis:true});
//brd.suspendUpdate();
var n = brd.create('slider',[[0.1,1.4],[1.1,1.4],[3,5,10]],{name:'n',snapWidth:1});

var f = brd.create('functiongraph',[function(x){return 1/(1+25*x*x);} ,-1.5,1.5]);
var doIt = brd.create('button', [0.1, 1.2, 'plot', plot]);
function plot() {
    var xy = [];
    for (i = 0; i< n.Value(); i++) {
        var xval = -1+2/(n.Value()-1)*i;
        var yval = 1/(1+25*xval*xval);
        xy[i] = brd.create('point',[xval,yval],{name:'', size:2});
    }

    var poly = JXG.Math.Numerics.lagrangePolynomial(xy);
    var g = brd.create('functiongraph',[poly,-1.5,1.5],{strokewidth:2});
    g.updateCurve();
    brd.update();
}
```

but that causes the new interpolants to be drawn on top of the old ones.

I've tried putting all the 'xy' definition and the call to `lagrangeInterpolation` inside a function, similar to the `plot` function above:

```
g = brd.create('functiongraph', [   ... definition goes here ... , -1.5,1.5]);
```

but I haven't had any luck with that either.   Clearly I'm missing out on something both simple and subtle, but I can't work out what, hence this query.   All I want is for the slider to immediately show the new interpolant through that number of points.  This should be I'm sure almost trivial, but several hours wrestling have produced no solutions.

Comment: Alfred Wasserman posted an answer in the googlegroups thread, but I recommend that you proceed here. I recommend that you make your own attempt available on JSfiddle. The general idea for that is: if the fix is simple then the question-JSfiddle can be edited to an answer-JSfiddle. I also recommend that you copy Alfred's answer to here (in case Alfred doesn't do that himself.)

Comment: About the intent of your question: my best guess is that you want to explore the case of having addtional points being added *in between* already existing points. It so happens I tried LagrangeInterpolation some time ago (for a diffferent problem), and I ran into the following: if all of the submitted points are exactly on, say, a parabola, then lagrange interpolation produces that parabola. But if even one of the points is off then the interpolation "explodes". Suddenly the coefficients of high powers become huge. Is my guess correct? Do you want to add new points *in between*?

Comment: Thank you indeed for your comments.  I'm just about to post a follow-up to Alfred's reply on google groups, the essence of which is that the problem is not merely about adding and subtracting individual points.  In fact, as the slider "n" moves from value v to value v+1, the only points in common are the end points -1 and 1.